# change ag-grid header background-color on gridready in typescript

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am using angular 6 . Where i am using ag-grid in a component. Is it possible to apply background color modification to ag-grid header using component CSS or using gridready columnapi or rowapi. I do not want to inherit and create a custom Header Component.I tried using headerClass attribute as mentioned on ag-grid documentation but that is not working . I tried overrriding .ag-header-container class in my CSS but it is not getting reflected.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by manipulating CSS Class in onGridReady.

```
css = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-
 viewport') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
  css[0].style.backgroundColor = "#d4d4d4";
```